# Is Google Wallet for digital good subsctiption page working?

Tags: android-pay

I m trying to integrate google wallet for digital goods in my application.

There are two modes: The test mode and the production mode.

However when I m trying to create any of the two , I fill in the respective form (sandbox)  https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/signup.html#?Businesssignup=euT3X4bAwIF0VcSOzYwXLVInNqs%3D  , I click "complete signup" but nothing happens. I am not redirected in another page or getting any message related my subscription.

Am I doing something wrong or you guys have the same issue.

Thnx